# Angular template inheritance

Tags: javascript, angular

Right now, I have dead simple use case of the inheritance, but for the life of me, I cannot get it to work.

**The use case**

My use case is thus:

- I have `BaseComponent` that has some `LoaderComponent`. It has methods `showLoader()` and `hideLoader()` for showing it and hiding it, respectively.
- Every loadable component, or even every component, extends this `BaseComponent`. Then, when there is network request, or we need to wait for a lot of stuff to render, we can just `showLoader()`, and then `hideLoader()` when the work is done.

**Implementation**

My implementation of this is pretty straightforward, but for some obscure reason, it's not working.

`base.component.ts`

```
//...
export class BaseComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(LoaderComponent) loader: LoaderComponent;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // caveman debugging, I know. Even worse is that I found myself placing breakpoint on this line of caveman debugging. SAD!
    console.log(this.loader);
  }

  showLoader() {
    this.loader.show();
  }

  hideLoader() {
    this.loader.hide();
  }
}
```

`base.component.html`

I use transclusion here, of course.

```
<ng-content> </ng-content>
<app-loader #loader></app-loader>
```

`contact.component.ts`

```
//...
@AutoUnsubscribe
export class ContactComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
    private senderService: SenderService,
    private messageSentService: MessageSentService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    super();
    // setup logic here...
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  sendEmail() // or whatever...
  {
     this.showLoader();
     // send the email
     // do the request
    this.emailSender = this.senderService.send(this.emailMessage);
    this.emailSender.subscribe((res) => {
      this.hideLoader();
      // handling the request here....
  }

  //...
}
```

`contact.component.html`

```
<app-base>
  <!-- the contact page -->
</app-base>
```

When I fire this up, what I see, in the developer console, is :

[image]

.

When I place my breakpoint on the caveman debugging in `BaseComponent.prototype.ngAfterViewInit()`, it hit twice. On the first instance, I get `this.constructor.name === "BaseComponent"`. However, on the second one, is the derived class : `this.constructor.name === "ContactComponent"`.

*The state of the decorated view child field `loader` isn't being passed down!!*

How do I fix this, and without resorting to some bullshit design like making the derived class **has-a** base class?

Comment: `contact.component.html` doesn't have an `<app-loader>` as far as I can tell.

Comment: But contact component **is-a** base component, which **has-a** loader component.

How do I say that in Angular?

Comment: A component cannot have two templates. I don't know how that would work exactly. Inheritance of decorators/component metadata is a bit wonky as it is but, regardless, a component cannot logically have multiple templates. How would they compose?

Comment: The point is modularity. DRY principle. If I do something like `export class B extends A` and then have to, inside `B`'s implementation, somehow reference `A`, that is incorrect. Why? Because it is no longer object-oriented programming, and because of that, is no longer modular code.

We'd have to be like `this.[inheritedProp] = this.[baseInstance].[inheritedProp]` **for every inherited prop on the base class just to even use its inherited logic**!

Comment: There are many ways to be DRY (something I strongly encourage) without inheritance. That said, you should consider that **a)** it doesn't make sense for a derived component to inherit its super's `template` _and_ specify its own template, and **b)** Angular is a terrible framework for DRY. Angular is absolutely stuffed to the gills with requirements to write redundant  boilerplate and often straight-up duplicate code.

Comment: Man, I wish I was writing in React+MobX now! At my last day job, we developed a system for this type of stuff!

Comment: Yes, angular does not provide template inheritance. For that particular requirement you could use a service that hides/shows the loader, and even trigger that from an HttpInterceptor whenever you make a request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem**

From What I understand ur question is you are not only using just component inheritance but template composition as well

```
contact.component.html

<app-base>
  <!-- the contact page -->
</app-base>
```

**Explanation**

Thing is You can not use Parent Template while inherit from it. a component has only one template.

in `contact.component.html` `<app-base>` means an instance of base-component as part of ur template.
so ur child component template is composed of base **not inherit from it** .

bcs Child Component template has not loader it it so its null.

Either use compose or inheritance

**Simple Solution**

while using component inheritance you have to copy all ur base template to child template

```
contact.component.html

<app-loader></app-loader>
```

**Advance Solution**

We can achieve almost what u want with [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

start with just an interface

```
export interface ILoader{
  showLoading ():void
  hideLoading ():void
}
```

create a app-loader wrapper that implement ILoader

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader-wrapper',
  template: `<ng-content> </ng-content>
            <app-loader></app-loader>`,
  styleUrls: ['./loader-wrapper.component.css']
})
export class LoaderWrapperComponent implements ILoader {

 @ViewChild(Loader) loader: Loader 
  showLoading (){
    this.loader.showLoading()
  }
  hideLoading (){
    this.loader.hideLoading()
  }
}
```

Create a baseComponent Class it will be base of all ur component which need loading **note it has no template**

```
class BaseComponent implements ILoader{
  @ViewChild(LoaderWrapperComponent) loader: LoaderWrapperComponent
  showLoading (){
    this.loader.showLoading();
  }
  hideLoading (){
    this.loader.hideLoading();
  }
}
```

now create components and inherit from it as use composition in template

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<app-loader-wrapper>
            // rest of ur component 
              </app-loader-wrapper>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent extends BaseComponent {
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I don't like the copy-and-paste implementation of `showLoader()`,`hideLoader()` methods, but I'll accept it!

Comment: why do you have implementation at two places. LoaderWrapperComponent  & BaseComponent ??

Comment: How can we use `@Input` & `@Output` decorators in the base component

Comment: @Saurabh47g yes it can be used

Comment: @Saurabh47g read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern